# R: Opposite order of start/stop times for difftime() input?

Tags: r, date, time

When using difftime() I am producing results that are (1) the incorrect sign and (2) incorrect values. Below is a working example of my code that replicates the problem.  As one can see, 1953 is BEFORE 1986. Isn't it supposed to produce a positively signed output?

```
x <- c("1953/05/24", "1930/04/16", "1986/04/01")
x <- as.Date(x, format="%Y/%m/%d")   

str(x)
Date[1:3], format: "1953-05-24", "1930-04-16", "1986-04-01"

y <- "1986/04/26"
y <- as.Date(y, format="%Y/%m/%d")   

str(y)
Date[1:1], format: "1986-04-26"

z <- difftime(x, y, units = "weeks") %>% as.numeric(.) %>% "*"(1/52.25)

z[1]

[1] -32.87765
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two mistakes in your code. First, the order of `x` and `y` [should be inversed](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/difftime.html) in `difftime()`. The second inaccuracy is the multiplier. A year has, [on average, 52.1775 weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

This should work:

```
z <- difftime(y, x, units = "weeks") / 52.1775
#> z
#Time differences in weeks ## Programmer's note: those are actually years.
#[1] 32.92333176 56.02852899  0.06844768
```

The calculation becomes easier if one uses days instead of weeks as units for the calculation, since this allows for the use of the well-known approximation of 365.25 days per year:

```
z <- difftime(y, x, units = "days") / 365.25
#> z
#Time differences in days ## Programmer's note: Those, too, are years:
#[1] 32.92265572 56.02737851  0.06844627
```

Within four significant digits the result is the same as before.